# How to avoid the annoying new line generated at SendAndLoad();

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

Please is there any workarround to avoid the new line generated while sending data using SendAndLoad(); in AS2 ?

I send `"00:00:12:36"`

But php output:

```
00
:00
:12:36
```

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird...

```
var stripped:String = data.split("\r").concat(""); // or \n alternatively
```

removes it from actionscript, but you'd rather fix the php.

Answer (score 0):

send:

```
escape("00:00:12:36")
```

and in PHP:

```
$myvar = urldecode($variableCameFromFlash);
```